# Trigger populating parent object values in child

Tags: apex, trigger

I have below trigger to populate master record's value in the child based on any update on Master. This code is getting error out for bulk loads. Can someone please suggest a best practice to overcome the limits? Bulk load might be for 300 records at a time.

Trigger:

```
trigger HCPREFERENCE on Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c (after insert,after update) {
    List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> updateTaskList = new List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c>();
    List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> TaskList = new List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c>();

    for (Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c a: trigger.new)
    {
        TaskList = [SELECT Id,Depth_Account__c 
                        FROM HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c
                        WHERE Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c= : a.Id]; 
        for(HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c task:TaskList)
        {
            task.Depth_Account__c = a.Account_oapi__c; 
            updateTaskList.add(task); 
        }          
    } 

    if(!updateTaskList.isEmpty())
    {
        update updateTaskList;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Google "bulkify trigger" to find out how to move the query out of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question looks like you aware of [Governor Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) in Salesforce. Have a look at [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) to understand how to handle them in Apex Triggers.
Try below untested code for your issue.

```
trigger HCPREFERENCE on Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c (after insert,after update) {
    List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> updateTaskList = new List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c>();
    List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> TaskList = new List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c>();
    Map<Id,Id> updatedMap = new Map<Id,Id>();

    for (Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c a: trigger.new)
    {
        //It's much better if apply condition for the expected change in this trigger before adding the Id into the set
        updatedMap.put(a.Id, a.Account_oapi__c);
    }

    TaskList = [SELECT Id,Depth_Account__c, Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c 
                FROM HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c
                WHERE Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c IN : updatedMap.keySet()]; 
    for(HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c task:TaskList)
    {
        task.Depth_Account__c = updatedMap.get(task.Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c); 
        updateTaskList.add(task); 
    }          

    if(!updateTaskList.isEmpty())
    {
        update updateTaskList;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hello highfive! That's great. It processes some more records.I have total 471 records to be operated. My code was processing 71 successfully, but yours doing for 200 still 271 errors out.Please find the error it shows in my loading tool.               Error received from salesforce.com.  Fields [].  Status code [CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY].  Message [HCPREFERENCE1: execution of AfterUpdatecaused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.Depth_Tracker_OAPI__cTrigger.HCPREFERENCE1: line 17, column 1].

Comment: For a particular user action number of controllers, triggers can be executed. So can't predict blindly where it exactly stops at. you have to check other related codes (triggers, classes) for bulk enabling. I have edited the answer since I have missed the field `Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c` in query

Comment: Trying to do it by batch apex called from trigger. Would request for your help if get any object there. Thanks a lot highfive!!:)

Comment: Hi highfive. Can you please help me in that approach?

Comment: Try your tasks and come to the forum if you are struggling with any technical issue. People definitely help for your fair questions. You also responsible for close your answered questions by marking it as answered, so that others don't waste their time to read and answer an already answered post.

Comment: Hi highfive!! I am extremely sorry for being late here. Thanks for your help that put up my baseline for the trigger.